# How to maintain file synchronization between multiple instances? so that only one instance will pick up the file and process it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spring-integration, amazon-sqs

I've an application which uses Spring Integration. My application listens from S3 bucket and if new files are available it process those files

Now this scenario will work smoothly if I've only one instance of my application. In case of multiple instances, there's a possibility that the file is processed by more than one application instance. What work around can be done here so that only one instance will process my file? Is there an in-built attribute in Spring Integration that I've missed which can be used to maintain the synchronization? Can we perform locking mechanism on S3 bucket Objects?

P.S Quartz and Zookeeper can be used here, but I want to see what other alternative can be used here

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347899/locking-an-s3-object-best-practice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Locking an s3 object best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347899/locking-an-s3-object-best-practice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that purpose Spring Integration suggests a:

```
 * Persistent file list filter using the server's file timestamp to detect if we've already
 * 'seen' this file.
 *
 * @author Artem Bilan
 */
public class S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter extends AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter<S3ObjectSummary> {
```

So, you can configure your `S3InboundFileSynchronizer` can be configured to supply this `S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` via:

```
/**
 * Set the filter to be applied to the remote files before transferring.
 * @param filter the file list filter.
 */
public void setFilter(FileListFilter<F> filter) {
```

The `S3PersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` has to be configured for any possible shared, persistent `MetadataStore`  implementation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#metadata-store.

For example starting with version `1.1`, the Spring Integration AWS provides this one:

```
/**
 * The {@link ConcurrentMetadataStore} for the {@link AmazonDynamoDB}.
 *
 * @author Artem Bilan
 *
 * @since 1.1
 */
public class DynamoDbMetaDataStore implements ConcurrentMetadataStore, InitializingBean {
```

P.S. There is nothing about Apache Camel in your question though...